# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS' in procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Why does my procedure give me:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CountAantalModules, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

when I try to alter it?

```
USE [SomaData]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CountAantalModules]    Script Date: 08/04/2011 15:09:09     ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CountAantalModules]
(
@prodorder as int,
@result int output
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT @result = COUNT(ORD.ORDERNUMMER) AS AantalModuleOrders
FROM        Kostenposten AS KP
INNER JOIN Orders AS ORD ON ORD.Ordernummer = KP.Ordernummer
WHERE ((KP.KPNR = '170' AND KP.SOORT='LadeFront' OR KP.SOORT='GlasLadeFront') OR
(KP.KPNR = '250' AND KP.SOORT='LadeFront')) AND ORD.PRODUCTIEORDER = (@prodorder)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting a variable and trying to select it at the same time.

I think instead of:

```
SELECT @result = COUNT(ORD.ORDERNUMMER) AS AantalModuleOrders
```

You might have just meant:

```
SELECT  COUNT(ORD.ORDERNUMMER) AS AantalModuleOrders
```

Or possibly:

```
SELECT @result = COUNT(ORD.ORDERNUMMER)
```

Comment: It's his output variable, so probably should remove the alias instead of the variable assignment

Answer (score 4):

Its an assignment to an (output) variable so cannot be aliased as its not a column in a result set.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you'll need quotes around the AantalModuleOrders, Since it is a string (want to name the column that way):

`SELECT COUNT(ORD.ORDERNUMMER) AS 'AantalModuleOrders'`

Comment: Thanks Tjekkles but I remove the AantalModuleOrders because I didn't really need it in my SP, it was a leftover from my original query string. Thanks all for responding!

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `AS AantalModuleOrders`.  You want the value of the `count(*)` in `@result`, so you don't need to give the column an alias name, as there is technically no column

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether the alias AantalModuleOrders is necessary, I would suggest removing the alias and using following statement:

```
SELECT @result = COUNT(ORD.ORDERNUMMER)
```